# Connect an iPad Pro to an older Macbook Pro using a generic USB-C to USB-A cable

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, usb

The older Macbook Pro I'm using doesn't have USB-C ports. The cable that came with the iPad Pro I'm using came with a USB-C to USB-C cable. I tried to use a USB-C to USB-A cable from a Huawei phone to connect the iPad and the Macbook, but there was no connection whatsoever.

Does it mean I'll have to get hold of a very specific USB-C to USB-A cable, such as a “Belkin USB-A to USB-C Cable (USB 3.1)” (cf. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209186#computer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no need to use that specific cable. Any standards-compliant USB-C to USB-A cable should work.

Comment: Far too many cables that come with cell phones today do not comply with the USB specifications.  Those that do meet the USB spec tend to be USB 2.0 cables that lack the "superspeed" connections necessary for USB 3.x communications.  Many cables that come with cell phones will leave out any data wires and connect only power.  Some cables will be Quick Charge or other cables which violate the USB spec to push more power for charging through, and by doing so will not provide any USB data connection.  Likewise, the USB-C cable that comes with iPad Pros and MacBooks meet the USB 2.0 spec only.